# Getting a section of an NSString

Tags: objective-c, url, nsstring, url-shortener, goo.gl

In my app i'm creating now i use goo.gl's url shortener api to shorted urls. I have it nearly working, I can send the longUrl to retrieve the short one in a NSString but it's in this format:

> {
>    "kind": "urlshortener#url",
>    "id": "http://goo.gl/something",
>    "longUrl": "http://somethinglonggggg/"
>   }

I just wondered if there is a way to just take the id (short url) from that.

Here's what I have so far:

```
NSString *longURL = urlText.text;
NSData *reqData = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"longUrl\":\"%@\"}", longURL] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest
                                requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url"]
                                cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                timeoutInterval:20];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:reqData];

NSError *err = [[NSError alloc] init];
NSData *retData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                        returningResponse:nil
                                                    error:&err];

if([err domain]) return;

NSString *retString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:retData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

if([retString rangeOfString:@"\"error\""].length) return;

NSLog(@" longUrl equals %@ ", longURL);
NSLog(@" retString equals %@ ", retString);

urlText.text = retString;
```

Comment: Are you sure the returned value is really a string, and not a dictionary? It seems it is a dictionary.

Comment: Hmm, i'm not sure to be honest, when I did            <NSLog(@" retString equals %@ ", retString);        it worked fine. If it was a dictionary how would i be able to get the url from it?

Comment: actually it's definitely a string, i tried to set it to a dictionary and wouldn't work.

Comment: It looks like JSON return - It might be easier to use one of the JSON parsing libraries.

Comment: Would you be able to help with JSON? :)

Comment: https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit

Answer (score 2):

You defenitively need to turn that into an NSDictionary (that JSON syntax is for a dictionary, or an object, however you want to call it.

The google API for Objective-C supports JSON parsing to turn the response into objects.

You can find it [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/).

If all you need is parsing the JSON, I would recommend either [JSONkit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit) or [TouchJSON](https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchJSON).

They both work in very similar ways, you give them the string and they will give you back objects.

The info for the individual usage of the libraries can be found on the readme of the respective project, there you will find how easy to use they are.

You would then acces the different values using:

```
NSString *short URL = [object valueForKey:@"id"];
```

This is the best way to interact with REST services.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Im glad it helped, please accept the answer if it solved your problem and tell me if you need any more help!